# How to traverse linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I can traverse the doubly linked list from head to tail, printout the list and also sort the elements accordingly.But I cant traverse it from the Tail pointer to Head pointer.I want to print the list by traversing backward.Also I want to delete the element from the sorted list and display the contents.

Comment: First and foremost, have you guaranteed the prev pointer chain is properly wired. You don't have to print tail-to-head to determine that. You can print head to tail, and dump not only the data, but the pointer values as well. If those are wrong, that's the first thing I'd fix. Actually, the very first thing I'd fix is using the `temp` pointer rather than the `Tail` member to walk the list. All you're doing there is breaking the very chain you want intact.

Comment: The doubly linked list in Standard C++ Library is the [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). To traverse it from end to the beginning use the reverse iterators. C developers don't have that so they are forced to wire the structures together as you do.

Comment: Why is `SortedInsert()` allocating 2 `Node` objects? It should be allocating only 1 `Node`. When the list has 1 element in it, the `Head` and `Tail` should be pointing at the same `Node`, not different `Node`s. And `SortedInsert()` isn't even initializing those 2 `Node` objects correctly.

Comment: @Ron I am not allowed to use std:list

Comment: @Remy ok i l correct that..

Comment: @WhozCraig I l change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SortedInsert()` method is allocating 2 `Node` objects, and not initializing them both correctly.  It should be allocating only 1 `Node` object, since you are inserting only 1 element.  When the list has 1 `Node` object in it, the `Head` and `Tail` pointers should be pointing at that `Node` object, not at different `Node` objects.

Try this instead:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::SortedInsert(const int& new_element) {

    Node* np = new Node(new_element);

    if (!Head)
    {
        Head = np;
        Tail = np;
    }
    else if (new_element < Head->Element)
    {
        np->Next = Head;
        Head->Prev = np;
        Head = np;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *cur = Head->Next;
        while ((cur) && (new_element >= cur->Element))
            cur = cur->Next;

        if (cur)
        {
            np->Prev = cur->Prev;
            np->Next = cur;
            cur->Prev->Next = np;
            cur->Prev = np;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail->Next = np;
            np->Prev = Tail;
            Tail = np;
        }
    }    
}
```

When deleting a `Node` object, that is a simple traversal to find the `Node` and then update the surrounding `Node` objects to not point at it anymore, eg:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::Delete(const int& del_element)
{
    Node *cur = Head;
    while (cur)
    {
        if (cur->Element == del_element)
        {
            if (cur->Prev)
                cur->Prev->Next = cur->Next;
            if (cur->Next)
                cur->Next->Prev = cur->Prev;
            if (cur == Head)
                Head = cur->Next;
            if (cur == Tail)
                Tail = cur->Prev;
            delete cur;
            break;
        }
        cur = cur->Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It works but during traversing from tail to head its not printing the first value  list 1 2 3 4 5       traversing from tail 5 4 3 2

Comment: @SatyajeetSen: The traversal code you showed looks fine, so you must not be setting up the nodes correctly, such that the `Prev` field of the `2` Node is not pointing at the `1` Node.

Comment: Yes it works like a charm thank you v much .There was error on my part.

Comment: How to delete pointers in destructor?while (Head != NULL && Tail !=NULL) {
  temp = Head;
  temp = Tail;
  Head = Head->Next;
  Tail=Tail->Prev;
  delete temp;
 }

Comment: You don't need to involve the `Tail` at all: `Node *temp = Head; while (temp) { Node *next = temp->Next; delete temp; temp = next; }` Alternatively: `while (Head) { Node *temp = Head; Head = Head->Next; delete temp; }`

Comment: thnks.. got it..we delete not the pointers but the pointing things like next and prev

Comment: I think you need to refresh your memory on how pointers work in general.